Tracking Button Presses in a Custom CKEditor5 Plugin With Angular
I can't figure out in Angular which plugin is pressed from ckeditor5
I'm using the change output event, but it doesn't seem to be providing the name of the pressed button.
Additionally, while I can see the list of commands for regular buttons, my plugin's command is missing. It appears that this functionality might not be supported in CKEditor 5. Is there an alternative approach I can take? I need to know which plugin pressed.
`
const button = new ButtonView();
      
const image='svg...' 

      button.set({
        icon: image,
        role: 'mybutton',
      });`

